# Google places API - Unable to add places using REST API

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I am trying to add missing places using the REST API support offered by Places API. Referred the document made available in this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place).

I am using POSTMAN Chrome app and I have tried to attempt adding missing places both using JSON and XML but in vain.

Here is the URL part,

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/xml?key=AIzaSyBRRp4IKzIR4aqm3WWyOW2kMU9J8sVBQMc&sensor=false

And here is the POST part as XML

```
<PlaceAddRequest>
    <location>
    <lat>10.702860</lat>
    <lng>77.759829</lng>
  </location>
  <accuracy>50</accuracy>
  <name>Vannapatti Solar plant</name>
  <phone_number>+91 98840 24699</phone_number>
  <address>Vannapatti, Semmengarai po, Mulanur tk</address>
  <type>Other</type>
  <website>www.askjuno.com</website>  
  <language>ta</language>
</PlaceAddRequest>
```

And here is the response I get from google places api,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlaceAddResponse>
    <status>INVALID_REQUEST</status>
</PlaceAddResponse>
```

I checked for any missing attributes as quoted in the documentation however, I couldn't find anything missing. Any help would be deeply appreciated.